# asp.net mvc setting XElement xml to empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xelement

How can I do something like XElement xml =empty;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the RemoveAll method to remove all child elements:

```
xml.RemoveAll();
```

This will leave you with your existing XElement as is but if you wanted to clear that out too just create a new XElement entirely.

```
xml = new XElement("name");
```